# The size of a quotient ring of Iwasawa algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am currently learning Iwasawa theory and trying to understand a proof of the following theorem:

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the integer ring of a local field $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$, with residue field $k$ of cardinality $q$. Consider the power series ring $\Lambda := \mathcal{O}[[T]]$, called the Iwasawa algebra.

> **Theorem**: Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a finitely generated torsion $\Lambda$-module. Assume that the intersection between the characteristic ideal $\mathrm{char}_{\Lambda}(\mathcal{M})$ and the principal ideal $(\omega_n(T) := (T+1)^{p^n}-1)$ is trivial for every natural number $n$. Then there exists $\nu \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that for sufficiently large $n$, we have
> $$
> \# (\mathcal{M} / \omega_n(T)) = q^{\lambda en+\mu p^n + \nu}.
> $$

When reading its proof, I found that a fact is frequently used without proof:

**FACT?**: Let $f(T)$ and $g(T)$ be *coprime* distinguished polynomials in $\Lambda$, then the quotient ring $\Lambda/(f(T), g(T))$ is a finite abelian group of order $q^n$ for some positive integer $n$.

**My question is: how to prove/disprove this "FACT?"** I have tried but found it hard to manipulate polynomials in the power series ring.

Thank you all for your comments and answers!

---

This "Fact" is also used to clarify the condition in the above theorem. Indeed, saying $\mathrm{char}_{\Lambda}(\mathcal{M})$ is coprime to $\omega_n(T)$ is equivalent to that $\mathcal{M}/\omega_n(T)$ is finite, granting the "FACT" above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clear, "coprime" in this context means $f(T), g(T)$ are coprime in $K[T]$ instead of $\Lambda$, otherwise the problem is trivial. This is essentially Lemma 13.7 in Washington's [Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-1934-7) (2nd edition).

So there are polynomials $f_1(T), g_1(T)\in K[T]$ such that $f_1(T)f(T)+g_1(T)G(T)=1$, by multiplying a sufficient large power of $\varpi$ (an uniformizer of $\mathcal O$) on both sides, we get $\varpi^n\in (f(T), g(T))$. By Weierstrass preparation theorem, any element in $\Lambda$ is congruent to a polynomial of degree less than $\deg f$ modulo $f$, and because $\mathcal O/(\varpi^n)$ is finite, there are at most finitely many equivalence classes modulo $(f(T), \varpi^n)$. Finally $\Lambda/(f, g)$ as a quotient group of $\Lambda/(f, \varpi^n)$ must be finite as well.

$\Lambda/(f,g)$ is a finite $\mathcal O$-module (where $\mathcal O$ is a DVR$\Rightarrow$PID), therefore isomorphic to $\oplus_{i=1}^m \mathcal O/(\varpi^{n_i})$ which has order $q^{\sum_{i=1}^m n_i}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now I see it!